# WAMPServer does nothing when i press download

Tags: download, wampserver

I'm using a 64 bit windows 10 pc and i'm trying to download WAMPServer for a project I'm starting however when i go to the website https://www.wampserver.com/en/ and hit download nothing happens. Can someone explain why? I've checked that i'm downloading the right version but nothing i've done seems to work.